# SSIS task Flat File Destination is saving .000 instead of 0.000

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flatfiledestination

I generate a tilde-delimited flat file out of several sql server 2008R2 tables. The columns I am having issues with are cost and price with $0 values. The SQL tables are set as [NUMERIC] (15,3) and so I do see "0.000" in them. When I use the Flat File Destination tasks, the numbers show up as ".000" which will get rejected by the feed. Any clue why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the values to string in SQL, i.e.:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(14), price) as Price
From my tb
```

You may need to fix the output column metadata to make sure it's a string, as well as the metadata in the destination flat file.

Comment: Looks like I won't have a choice on that one. I was hoping to keep it as a price but it won't matter for the feed. Thank you for answering.